# Passing arguments to ForeignKey class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using [stdimage](http://code.google.com/p/django-stdimage/) to auto resize my images, I have something like that :

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = stdimage.StdImageField(upload_to="images/uploads/", size=(width, height))


class Nevermind(models.Model):
    w, h = 300, 150
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)

class Nevermind2(models.Model):
    w, h = 100, 100
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
```

So I would like pass width and heigth as arguments to the Image class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your goal is, but you could try using [model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods) to define extra paramenters with the models.

```
#model
class Nevermind2(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(image)

    def size(self):
        w,h = 100,100
        return w, h

#example use
>>> a = Nevermind2.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> a.size()
(100,100)
>>> w,h = a.size()
>>> w
100
>>> h
100
```

Comment: thanks, but in fact what I want is something like that :
image = models.ForeignKey(image, size=(100,100)) and get size argument  in the Image class

Comment: are you trying to store thumbnail sizes of a full size image? If so, try having 3 different imagefields in the original model all defined with different sizes, exlcude the 2nd and 3rd fields in the form, and when you process the form, submit the original image to the 2nd and 3rd fields before calling the save.

Comment: hmm no, I want for example Nevermind class sends (182,80) to Image class by the foreignKey field, and Nevermind2 class sends (640,480) by the same way. And same thing for others classes which have a ForeignKey on Image class

Comment: are you trying to get those sized images from `Image` to use in `Nevermind`? Maybe it's just me that's confused. You should edit/update your question to describe in more detail what you want to accomplish